# PDO error: " SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error " When updating database

Tags: php, pdo

I am getting an error when updating a database using PDO.
I am new to PDO so maybe the problem is a small one and I just don't understand.
*Funny thing about the error, the command works fine and the database does actually get updated.*
But it still returns an error back at me.

**Code:**

```
try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE $page SET $section = :new_content WHERE $section = '$old_content'");
    $stmt->execute(array(
        'new_content' => $new_content
    ));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "Database updated!";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR UPDATING CONTENT: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Error:**
ERROR UPDATING CONTENT: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

I literally have no idea where the problem could be because its very vaque and I haven't been able to find anyone with the same problem.

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injection, even though you're (partially/incorrectly) using prepared statements and placeholders. Just because YOU'RE the one providing the data being insert doesn't mean you can't inject yourself.

Comment: Are you referring to the variables $page & $section? They are both taken from the fixed ID of html elements.

so you are saying even they are potentially harmful?

Comment: `$old_content` would be the big red flag for me. **ANY** dynamic data going into a query string is potentially harmful. just because you pulled it out of a DB doesn't mean it's safe. e.g. consider something like `update users set name='Miles T. O\'Brien' where name='Miles O'Brien';`. you escape the newly updated name, but pulled the original name from the db to begin with, and now you've injected yourself a syntax error.

Comment: Ah yes ok. I never thought of that. Thanks Marc.

Comment: You are trying to fetch an UPDATE query

Comment: @Ruwantha How do you do that?

Comment: @AlxVallejo $pdo->prepare("SELECT....  not $pdo->prepare("UPDATE....

Comment: In other words, there's no succinct way to return rows from an update query?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You do not use fetchAll(),as in

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

with update or insert queries. Removing this statement should rectify the problem.

Comment: So what is the correct method for executing update queries if not this?

Comment: @deeperDATA, Just the execute statement should be enough. Calling fetchAll() is needed only for select queries.

Comment: I suggest that the correct method is update(). Try to use this for updating your tables

Answer (score 14):

Just to note, another possible reason for this error is if you make a second database call with the variable $stmt inside of an existing  parent $stmt loop.

```
     $stmt = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {  //second use of $stmt here inside loop
```

Comment: This was my issue, apparently PDO doesn't like the variable being reset.

Comment: @MattCavanagh do you mind sharing how you worked around this? I'm running into it now...

Comment: Silly of me, but just realized I was using the same variable name, `$stmt`, inside the loop. I've made it unique `$stmt_delete` and it works.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue I had too.

Comment: This is my situation, how to fix it? (how to reset  the `$stmt`?

Comment: @candlejack Use a different variable than $stmt inside of the loop