# PHP, MySQL, PDO - Get result from UPDATE query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am updating a row in a table, and trying to return the updated row, as per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388025/how-to-get-id-of-the-last-updated-row-in-mysql?#answer-1751282).

My code is the following:

```
$sql = "SET @update_id := '';
        UPDATE testing SET status='1', id=(SELECT @update_id:=id)
        WHERE status='0' LIMIT 1; 
        SELECT @update_id;";

$db->beginTransaction();
try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    echo count($stmt->fetchAll());

    $db->commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

But I always get the following error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Which seems to be due to the `$stmt->fetchAll()`, according to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979510/pdo-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-when-updating-database?#answer-12980031). If I take that line out, the row is updated appropriately.

So, how do I run the multi-query statement (multi-statement query!?) using PDO, and obtain the results from the `SELECT`?

**EDIT 1**

I *DO NOT* need the *count* of the rows updated. I need the actual *ID* of the row.

Table Schema

```
  id   |   someCol  |  status
 ----- |   -------  |  ------
   1   |     123    |    0
   2   |     456    |    0
   3   |     789    |    0
   4   |     012    |    0
```

- Look at the table,
- find the first status=0,
- update the row,
- return the id of the row that was updated

The count is of zero interest to me, as the query has `LIMIT 1` hard-coded into it.

The whole point of the line

```
count($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Is a pass/fail condition.

```
if(count ==1){
    ... do something with the returned id ...
}else{
    ... do something else ...
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Obviously this issue is simple to get around with two separate queries. I would prefer to have this in one single query. Both a preference, as well as an opportunity to learn.

Comment: are you trying to check if your query was successful here?

Comment: What's the point of trying to get count of updated rows if you're always updating only one row with `LIMIT 1` and `$stmt->execute()` will return true or false of operation.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Within the very first sentence of the question, "... and trying to return the updated row...".

Comment: @TheDrot tIf the count is 1, then there would be a result to read, and I can proceed with that code. If the count is zero, then there is no result, and it can stop right there.

Comment: answers are below then, take a peek ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do the `SELECT @update_id` as a separate query -- you can't put multiple queries in a single statement. So do:

```
$sql = "SET @update_id := '';
        UPDATE testing SET status='1', id=(SELECT @update_id:=id)
        WHERE status='0' LIMIT 1";
try{
    $db->beginTransaction();
    $db->query($sql); // no need for prepare/execute since there are no parameters
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT @update_id");
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $id = $row['@update_id'];
    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $db->rollBack();
    exit();
}
```

Comment: If it's a "cannot be done" scenario, due to limitations of the PDO, then two queries will suffice. Much thanks.

Comment: @Birrel Only mysqli has a method for doing multiple queries in a single call, `mysqli_multi_query`. But it's a PITA to use, and I've never seen a convincing argument for using it.

Comment: Keep in mind that if this were part of another transaction, this would not work. MySQL doesn't support nested transactions.

Comment: @AlxVallejo That's true of any code that creates a transaction, it's not specific to this. His original code had the transaction, the question was just about how to execute two statements.

Answer (score 5):

You're right about getting the exception SQLSTATE[HY000] for `$stmt->rowCount();`

The problem is, you cannot fetch an UPDATE query because these queries simply don't return values. To circumvent this, use rowCount().

As written in the PHP documentation, *[PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)*

Check out this example.

```
<?php
/* Updating rows from the PICNIC table*/
$update = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE ... PICNIC');
$update->execute();

/* Return the number of rows affected */
   echo $updateCount = $update->rowCount();

?>
```

Comment: Just noticed you have Limit set to 1. Do you intend to verify if the update query went through?

Comment: Review edited question. I am not concerned with the count, nor was that stated in the question.

Comment: Just to add if you execute an update of an item with the value it already is, then rowcount will return 0 and not 1.  Which was unexpected for me, I didn't expect it to compare before updating.

Answer (score 2):

It's failing on `->fetchAll()` because an `UPDATE` query does not return any rows/data.

What you want to do, is check out [`PDO::rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php). This returns the count of how many rows have been affected by your query.

```
echo $stmt->rowCount();
```

<sup>*This was posted assuming you're trying to check if your query was successful.*</sup>

Comment: Review edited question. I am not concerned with the count, nor  was that stated in the question.

Comment: @Birrel See what Barmar has answered with.