# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error for insertion in to the database

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issue of SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error, howevere my code works fine, it updates insert and selects but still i get the error.

The last error I received is as follows:

```
Marker - 11 Jul 2016 16:34:44
[11-Jul-2016 14:58:24 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception   'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in      /Users/mughery/Documents/Business/websites/LoginBusinessDoor    /_/class.Database.inc:46
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/mughery/Documents/Business/websites/LoginBusinessDoor/_/class.Database.inc(46): PDOStatement->fetchAll(5)
#1 /Users/mughery/Documents/Business/websites/LoginBusinessDoor/_/class.Database.inc(147): Database->query('UPDATE customer...', Array)
#2 /Users/mughery/Documents/Business/websites/LoginBusinessDoor/index.php(116): Database->update('customer', '_customer_id', 10, Array)
#3 {main}
  thrown in /Users/mughery/Documents/Business/websites/LoginBusinessDoor/_/class.Database.inc on line 46
```

I have been following a tutorial and the code in the tutorial works fine, however my code does not. What could possibly be the problem?

My code is as follows. I get an error and the Redirect does not work either.

```
            public function query($sql, $params = array()){

                    $this->_error = false;
                    if($this->_query = $this->_connection->prepare($sql)){
                      $x = 1;

                    if(count($params)){
                        foreach($params as $param ){
                            $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                            $x++;
                        }
                    }

                if($this->_query->execute()){
                $this->_results =   $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count =      $this->_query->rowCount();             
                    }
                    else{
                        $this->_error = true;
                    }
                }
                return $this;
    }
```

The insert method is as follows:

```
         public function insert($table, $fields=array()){


                $keys= array_keys($fields);
                $values = '';
                $x=1;

                foreach($fields as $field){

                    $values .= '?';
                    if($x < count($fields)){

                        $values .= ', ';
                    }
                    $x++;
                }

                $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table}(`".implode('`, `',$keys)."`)VALUES({$values})";

                if(!$this->query($sql,$fields)->error()){

                    return true;
                }

            return false;
    }
```

And this is the context for calling the code:

```
 <?php
    ob_start(); 
    require_once "core/init.php"; 
     $output ='';
    //var_dump(Token::check(Input::get('token')));

if(Input::exists()){
    //if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))){
                $validate = new Validation();
                $validatation = $validate->check($_POST, 
                        array(      
                                'username'  =>array(
                                        'requierd'=>true,
                                        'min'=>5,
                                        'max'=>400,
                                        'unique'=>'customer'),

                                'uname'     =>array(

                                                'requierd'=>true,
                                                'min'     => 5,
                                                'max'     => 50
                                ),

                                'pwd'       =>array(
                                                'requierd'=>true,
                                                'min'=> 9

                                ),

                                'confirm'=>array(
                                                'requierd'=> true,
                                                'matches' => 'pwd'
                                ),
                          )
                    );
                    //Storing error bellow.                 
                if($validate->passed()){
                        //$output.= 'You have been successfully registerd';             

                        $customer = new Customer();

                        $salt = Hash::salt(32);

                        try{
                            $customer->create(array(
                                'username'  =>Input::get('username'),
                                'password'  =>Hash::make(Input::get('pwd'), $salt),
                                'salt'      =>$salt,
                                'name'      =>Input::get('uname'),
                                'joined'    =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                'group'     =>1 
                            ));
                    Session::flash('home', 'You have been registerd and can now log in!');
                    Redirect::to('index.php');  
                    }catch(Exception $e){ die($e->getMessage()." Here is the error "); }    
                }else{
                        $output.='<div class="col-md-12"><div class="jumbotron"><p>';
                                        //output errors
                                        $x =0;
                                        foreach($validate->errors() as $key => $error){
                                            $output.= $error. ', ';
                                        }
                        $output.='</p></div></div>';
                }
    //}         
}
 ?>
 <?php include"_/php/header.php";?>
```

```
    <?php echo $output; ?>  


    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">                       
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2> Sign Up</h2>
                </div>
                        <form class="panel-body" action="signup.php" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo escap(Input::get('username')); ?>"/>

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Username</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="uname" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo escap(Input::get('uname')); ?>"/>
                                        <span>This Name will appear when your application is listed, your real name wont be seen except by the bankers. </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">    
                                        <label for="password">Create Password</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="pwd" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">    
                                        <label for="repassword">Confirm Password</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="repassword" name="confirm" placeholder="Password" value=""/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">          
                                        <label>
                                            <input id="terms" name="terms"  value="off"type="checkbox" unchecked>
                                            Terms and Condition

                                        </label>


                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="token"  value="<?php echo Token::generate();?>">
                                <input class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" name="register" value="Sign Up">

                        </form>
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <h4>Have an account? Log in<h4>
                        </div>      
        </div>
     </div><!--End col-md-6 --> 
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>        
 </div><!--End row-->
 </section><!--End section-->
    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

the last two codes are in the same file signup.php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO error: " SQLSTATE\[HY000\]: General error " When updating database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979510/pdo-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-when-updating-database)

Comment: What do u mean, can you clarify please

Comment: Pls read and interpret the accepted answer. It is clear and to the point.