# Unexpected PDO "General error 2050" depending on configuration

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have some code where variable $query is supposed to hold different PDOStatement objects, one replaced by another:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("select * from ... ");
$query->execute();
while ($tmp=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   ...;
}

//unset($query);
$query = $conn->query("select * from ... ");
while ($tmp=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ....;
}
```

With such code I get "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2050" from PDO on the line with the last fetch. But if I uncomment line with "unset" - it starts working correctly.

Any idea of what could it be?

PS Without using unset, it also works with PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES = true

UPD 
Here is error code description from MySQL site:

Error: 2050 (CR_FETCH_CANCELED)
Message: Row retrieval was canceled by mysql_stmt_close() call

Comment: it's probably a typo but `while ($tmp=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) {` is missing the closing `)`

Comment: Yes, a typo, thank you. Just corrected.

Comment: Really curious about a reason for downvoting

Answer (score 0):

in some php versions error 2050 happen because you must empty the var that holds the object with the result of the query
see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36631355/2613863

in [Matt Cavanagh  commet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2187971/matt-cavanagh)