# updated values are displaying only after refreshing the page

Tags: php, forms, session, browser

i am trying to update name ,email , image informations in form.

name, email was updating fine, but image was not saving in folder, so i removed `;` in below line :

`if ($user_home->update($uname,$email, $phone, $uid));` ,

now once we click on "save" button, images are saving in folders,

but name & emails are displaying old values, & after refreshing page displaying updated values. but i want to **display updated values once we click on save button.**

**form**

```
<form action="profile.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Name : 
<?php echo $row['userName'] ?> <br/>
Email :
<?php echo $row['userEmail'] ?> <br>

<h3>photo</h3>

<input type="file" name="photo" id="fileSelect"><br> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**code for name ,email**

```
<?php
include 'home.php';

// session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    header("Location: index.php");
die();
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>



    <?php

    $FORM['uname'] = "";
    $FORM['txtuname'] = "";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // new data
    $uname = $_POST['txtuname'];
    $email = $_POST['txtemail'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $uid = (isset($_GET['userID']) ? intval($_GET['userID']) : -1);

    // query
    if ($user_home->update($uname,$email, $phone, $uid)); // This is the line
    {
        header("Location: profile.php");
        die(); 
    }
    }

    ?>
```

**code for image**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_FILES["photo"]["error"])){ 
if($_FILES["photo"]["error"] > 0){ 
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"] . "<br>"; 

} else{ 
$allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png"); 
$filename = $_FILES["photo"]["name"]; 
$filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"]; 
$filesize = $_FILES["photo"]["size"]; 

// Verify file extension 
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format."); 

// Verify file size - 5MB maximum 
$maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; 
if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit."); 

// Verify MYME type of the file 
if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){ 
// Check whether file exists before uploading it 
if(file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"])){ 
echo $_FILES["photo"]["name"] . " is already exists."; 

} else{ 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]); 

echo "Your file was uploaded successfully."; 
} 
} else{ 

echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file - please try again."; 
} 

} 

} else{ 
echo "Error: Invalid parameters - please contact your server administrator."; 
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the select query after the update query, otherwise you are getting the old info and then update the record in the database.

```
<?php
include 'home.php';

// session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}

$FORM['uname'] = "";
$FORM['txtuname'] = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// new data
$uname = $_POST['txtuname'];
$email = $_POST['txtemail'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$uid = (isset($_SESSION['userSession']) ? intval($_SESSION['userSession']) : 0);

// query
if ($uid > 0 && $user_home->update($uname,$email, $phone, $uid)) // This is the line
{
    header("Location: profile.php");
    die(); 
}
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

Or you can use this custom update:

```
// query
if ($uid > 0)
{
    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("UPDATE tbl_users SET userName=:uname, 
                              userEmail=:email, phone=:phone WHERE userID=:uid");
    $stmt->execute(array(
                 ":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession'],
                 ":email" => $email,
                 ":phone" => $phone,
                 ":uname" => $uname
    ));
    header("Location: profile.php");
    die(); 
}
```

Comment: you saved my day buddy, now its working fine, one more issue i am getting is once i upload image and click on `save` button, images are saving in folder, thats fine. but its displaying error : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error` , i guess some problem with code part of image, can you please help me for that too ?

Comment: What is the query that fails

Comment: no , its working fine, its uploading images to folder fine, but it display error message : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error` once we click on save button, please check `code for image` part in question.... i checked [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979510/pdo-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-when-updating-database) , but i did't got what to do in my case.....

Comment: Try with my updated code. `$_GET['userID']` is unnecessary given you have `$_SESSION['userSession']`

Comment: i replaced this line : `$uid = (isset($_GET['userID']) ? intval($_GET['userID']) : -1);` with this line `$uid = (isset($_SESSION['userSession']) ? intval($_SESSION['userSession']) : 0);` , but it did't worked for me....

Comment: And did you add `$uid > 0 && ` in the if

Comment: add `echo 111;` before the if and `echo 222;` after the if and see where warning message appears - before or after which echo

Comment: code : `echo 111; if ($uid > 0 && $user_home->update($uname,$email, $phone, $uid)); // This is the line
{
    header("Location: profile.php");
    die(); 
}
}  echo 222; , error : `222
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

333`

Comment: sorry, check this one : code : echo 111; if ($uid > 0 && $user_home->update($uname,$email, $phone, $uid)); // This is the line { header("Location: profile.php"); die(); } } echo 222; , error : `111 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error 222`

Comment: it seems the error comes from `$user_home->update`. Check if you have unique columns set in the table or just execute the update query manually with the data that you are submitting in the form

Comment: please check here : http://prnt.sc/cy8uk9 , also please tell me `how to execute the update query manually with the data that  i am submitting in the form`

Comment: I edited my answer + I noticed another error in the code before `// This is the line` :) there is `;` which means that the body of the `if statement` was executed each time no matter if it is true or not :)

Comment: i updated your code, images are not uploading , can you please check...

Comment: may be it's because you are getting redirected by `header("Location: profile.php");`

Comment: instead of `custom update` if i remove `;` from `if ($uid > 0 && $user_home->update($uname,$email, $phone, $uid))` , than images will upload but this error is still there : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error`

Comment: now i removed `redirection` & using same file in header as like `header("Location: profile1.php"); but still the error exists....

Comment: Debug the code in $user_home->update. If you can try to print the query that is executed in this function.

Comment: Ok, you got it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126594/discussion-between-abcd-and-krasipenkov).